# $∀f ∈ L(R)\ ∃\ cf > 0 : ∀x1, x2 ∈ \Bbb R : |f(x1) − f(x2)| < cf |x1 − x2|$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

> Let $L (R)$ denote the set of real functions on $\Bbb R$ satisfying the condition:
>   $∀f ∈ L(R)\ ∃\ cf > 0  : ∀x1, x2 ∈ R : |f(x1) − f(x2)| < cf |x1 − x2|$
>   Show that $L (R)$ is subspace of linear real-space function.

Comment: what have you done to try and show this?

Answer (score 1):

Zero function is there. For $f,g$ in the set, find $c,d>0$ such that the properties hold, then 
\begin{align*}
|(f+g)(x_{1})-(f+g)(x_{2})|&\leq|f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})|+|g(x_{1})-g(x_{2})|\\
&<c|x_{1}-x_{2}|+d|x_{1}-x_{2}|\\
&=(c+d)|x_{1}-x_{2}|, 
\end{align*}
$f+g$ is there. For multiplication, if $\alpha=0$, surely $\alpha f=0$ is there, if $\alpha\ne 0$, then the corresponding constant would be $c/|\alpha|$.

Comment: please break it into pieces . becasue i don't understand your equation.

Comment: @OlaNowak What part you don't understand ? please clarify.